# Why does ant think package doesn't exist?

Tags: java, ant, classpath, javac

I have the following directory structure:

```
MyApp/
    src/main/java/
        com/
            myapp/
                api/
                    IFizz
                    FizzLoader
                impl/
                    core/
                        FizzImpl
                    Cat
                    Dog
                    Tree
                    ...many other objects
    src/test/java
        ...
    build/
    lib/
    ...
```

I want to only compile everything under `src/main/java/com/myapp/api` **as well as** `com.myapp.impl.core.FizzImpl`, such that `Cat`, `Dog`, `Tree` etc. do not get compiled (and are thus excluded).

In by Ant build (`build.xml`), I configure the following `main.compile.path`:

```
<path id="src.path">
    <fileset dir="src/main/java/com/myapp/api">
        <include name="**.*java"/>
    </fileset>
</path>
<path id="lib.main.path">
    <fileset dir="lib/main">
        <include name="**/*.jar"/>
    </fileset>
</path>
<path id="main.compile.path">
    <path refid="src.path" />
    <path refid="lib.main.path" />
    <fileset dir="src/main/java" includes="com/myapp/impl/core/**/*" />
</path>
```

And then the following `main-compile` target:

```
<target name="main-compile">
    <javac includeantruntime="false" srcdir="src/main/java/com/myapp/api"
            destdir="gen/bin/main" debug="on">
        <classpath refid="main.compile.path"/>
    </javac>
</target>
```

When I run `main-compile`, I get the following build exception:

```
[javac] /home/myuser/eclipse/workspace/MyApp/src/main/java/com/myapp/api/FizzLoader.java:14: package com.myapp.impl.core does not exist
[javac] import com.myapp.impl.core.FizzImpl;
[javac]  ...(omitting rest of trace but available upon request)
```

Here, `FizzLoader` is creating an instance of `FizzImpl`, and so I need this on the compile path.

Why does Ant not see the `com.myapp.impl.core.FizzImpl` that I have selectively added to the `main.compile.path`? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The classpath of javac should refer to directories and jar files containing the root of compiled class files trees. It should not refer to Java files.

Similarly, the source directory should refer to the root of the package tree of the source files. Not to directories corresponding to packages, inside the package tree.

Your compile task should look like

```
<target name="main-compile">
    <javac includeantruntime="false" 
           srcdir="src/main/java"
           destdir="${gen.bin.main.dir}" 
           debug="on"
           includes="com/myapp/api/**/*.java, com/myapp/impl/core/FizzImpl/**/*.java">
        <classpath refid="lib.main.path"/>
    </javac>
</target>
```